# why use svd() to invert a Hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrices, svd, cholesky-decomposition

In MATLAB, I compared elapsed time to invert a Hermitian matrix using `inverse()`, `svd()`, and `chol()`. `svd()` took the longest. So is there any reason to prefer `svd()` to the other two methods?

`chol()` was the fastest. Is there any reason *not* to prefer the `chol()`?

Comment: Is your matrix positive definite?  chol() won't work if it isn't positive definite.

Comment: Yes, the matrix can be assumed to be positive definite. So, my question is based on the assumption that all three methods actually give answers.

I'm going through Gil Strang's linear algebra course (for the second time) now, but he doesn't mention Cholesky. It's been decades since I studied linear algebra so I'm re-learning most of this :) and have been googling things as well.